# How to count total lines changed by a specific author in Gitlab CE?

Tags: statistics, gitlab

Is there a method(API) I can invoke which will count the lines changed by a specific author in Gitlab CE?
for example:

> someone   add     del
>
> xxx        100        10

and i don't want to pull all code to my local, because it's so large.